# How to normalize data by different schemas based on the entity parent's value with normalizr?

Tags: javascript, schema, normalizr

I'd like to normalize data in this format:

```
    [
      {
        id: 3,
        status: "active",
        created: "2017-07-03T15:36:11+02:00",
        published: "2017-07-03T15:38:07+02:00",
        linkables: [
          {
            data: {
              content: "Text content of the linkable",
              id: 200
            }
            linkable_type: "content",
            module_id: 3,
            module_type: "case_study"
          },
          {
            data: {
              content: "https://foobar.wee/url_of_the_media.png",
              id: 205
            }
            linkable_type: "media",
            module_id: 3,
            module_type: "case_study"
          },
        ]
      },
      ...
    ]
```

into something like this:

```
    {
      entities: {
        contents: {
          200: {
            content: "Text content of the linkable",
            id: 200
          }
        },
        media: {
          205: {
            content: "https://foobar.wee/url_of_the_media.png",
            id: 205
          }
        },
        linkables: {
          3_case_study_content_200: {
            data: 200, // in the contents key
            linkable_type: "content",
            module_id: 3,
            module_type: "case_study"
          },
          3_case_study_media_205: {
            data: 205, // in the media key
            linkable_type: "media",
            module_id: 3,
            module_type: "case_study"
          }
        },
        caseStudies: {
          3: {
              id: 3,
              status: "active",
              created: "2017-07-03T15:36:11+02:00",
              linkables: ["3_case_study_content_200", "3_case_study_media_205"]
          }
        }
      },
      result: [3]
    }
```

Using the 2.x version of the normalizr makes this easy thanks to this PR https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/pull/132 that adds a function one can use to dynamically decide what scheme to use when normalizing by the value in the parent object.

However, in the version 3.x.x this additional function did not make it. According to the [docs](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/blob/master/docs/api.md#schema), I'd say that `schemaAttribute` does the job.

Having this piece of code unfortunately does not give me the wanted result...

```
    export const caseStudies = new schema.Entity('caseStudies');

    export const media = new schema.Entity('media',);
    export const content = new schema.Entity('contents');

    export const linkablesSchema = new schema.Entity(
      'linkables',
      {},
      {
        idAttribute: (itm) => {
          const id = itm.data.id;
          return `${itm.module_id}_${itm.module_type}_${itm.linkable_type}_${id}`;
        }
      }
    );

    export const linkableSchemaMap = {
      content,
      media
    };

    caseStudies.define({
      linkables: [linkablesSchema]
    });


    export const lschema = new schema.Array(linkableSchemaMap, (value, parent) => {
      return parent.linkable_type; // this would replace the PR mentioned above?
    });

    linkablesSchema.define({
      data: lschema
    });
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way that came to mind is to use `processStrategy` inside of the `linkablesSchema` options to apply `linkable_type` value as a property:

```
export const caseStudies = new schema.Entity("caseStudies");
export const mediaSchema = new schema.Entity("media");
export const contentsSchema = new schema.Entity("contents");
export const linkablesSchema = new schema.Entity("linkables", {}, {
  idAttribute: itm => `${itm.module_id}_${itm.module_type}_${itm.linkable_type}_${itm.data.id}`,
  processStrategy: (value) => ({ 
    ...value,
    data: value.data.id,
    [value.linkable_type]: value.data,
  })
});

linkablesSchema.define({
  content: contentsSchema,
  media: mediaSchema
})

caseStudies.define({
  linkables: [linkablesSchema]
});

normalize(data, [caseStudies]);
```

And here's the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/j7pkkz8kx9). Hope it helps.

Comment: How about some response?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, currently facing a problem when the the linkable contains another array of linkables in its data object, the main problem is solved however. Thank you

Comment: Glad to help. I'll try to help with nested linkables, if you provide more info

Comment: I'm having an issue with nested linkables... Imagine, for example, that the linkable has in its data object another linkable array that I want to normalizaze by the linkablesSchema again, I am running into  `Cannot read property 'normalize' of undefined at visit`

Comment: Updated the sandbox. Is this what you mean?

Comment: I forked your sandbox, https://codesandbox.io/s/ppnq2z72wj this is what I mean. I don't have a clue why it is working in the sandbox but in my app it throws the error mentioned above :/

Comment: I put the same data in the sandbox (did not save it) and it works there... In my app, i got the same version of normalizr. Weird. @streletss

Comment: Weird indeed.. I'll try to recreate

Comment: No need. Figured it out. I dug into normalizr's code and it turned out that one of the schemas was undefined. The problem was the order of imports across multiple files. What is weird is, that webpack nor IDE was complaining. Anyway... Thank a lot for your help.